# How to specify identity when using SSH agent?

Tags: linux, ssh, certificate, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I've got a slightly unusual use-case...

I'm using SSH via certificates, (where the authentication mechanism isn't just a signature from a private key, but also presentation of a signed cert).

I have many endpoints/servers and different environments that I access in the same session, thus my `ssh-agent` is "loaded" with many identities at a time.

I'm using the `ssh-agent` as it provides a number of niceties like `forwarding`.

The issue I'm hitting is, my VM endpoints all have an `sshd_config` with `MaxAuthTries` set to a low value. This cannot be changed. What I've noticed is, when the agent has many identities (certs/keys) added to it, and I try to connect to a given endpoint, the agent seems to loop through all added identities, trying each in turn, which is sometimes triggering the `MaxAuthTries` rule, resulting in `Too many authentication failures`.

So my question is, whilst using the `ssh-agent` is there a way to specify which identity it's got which it should use?

I want to use the `ssh-agent` but don't want it to cycle through each identity trying each one.

I thought of using a hosts config file, but it's going to be a manual effort given the number of blades I maintain.

I've tried the `-o` flag, but this seems to not look at loaded identities in the agent, and instead try to find them "locally" - where locally is the current SSH context.

Thanks for reading...

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a distinction based on hostname? If so, you can try putting the following in ~/.ssh/config.

```
Host *.domain1.com
User <your_username>
IdentityFile <certificate>

Host *.domain2.com
User <your_username>
IdentityFile <certificate>
```

This solution is as mentioned in the comment from the OP only workable if there is some kind of logic in the names of the hosts. With this I mean being able to determine the to be used key from the hostname, domainname, ... of what you are connecting to.

Comment: yep but as I mentioned in the question, its too manual, I have hundreds of hosts...